# What is the easiest way to require the user to fill in default fields of the User model like first name and last name in Django in UserCreationForm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using Django built-in authentication views and form to create a registration/login system, and I'm using the UserCreationForm to register a user but only the username is required. I only want to make other User fields required as well. What is the simplest way to do that without creating a new user model?

Here are my forms:

```
# Create user registration form class.
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
```

And here are my views:

```
def register(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context = {
                'user': request.user,
            }
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'), context)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('register'))
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Project 3: TODO")

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you share your views and forms? You can override the fields on the form to make them required

Comment: I have just shared them, see post edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the fields for first and last name on the form to make them required. Note, this won't change the fact that the database table still allows null values for those fields

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
```

Comment: If I don't want null values, can I just add "blank=False" between parentheses as well?

Comment: `blank=False` is only for the model field validation you would need to add `null=False` to a model field to not allow null values. However, since you do not want to provide your own custom user model you cannot change the existing model's fields. It also does not make sense to pass `blank` to a form field, `required` is the form field equivilant

Comment: So, just to confirm, are you saying I don't need to create a custom user model and set the fields to 'not null' if I use blank for the form validation? From a security standpoint, could the 'required' attribute be bypassed, I don't know, say by modifying the request with a browser proxy for example?

Comment: Also, I don't understand what difference there is between changing the blank attribute of a field or its required attribute. You say it's not possible to change fields, but isn't changing required to True also a change?

Comment: Form validation is done in the view on the server-side, there is no danger that a user could bypass this validation. Setting `required=True` on the form fields will ensure that the user has to fill in those fields.

Comment: You're just changing the form that is generated, you are not changing anything internal to the model. Setting `required=True` will ensure that those fields are passed when your form is used but it does not prevent a developer from say creating a user from a shell without those fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213564/discussion-between-thomas-and-iain-shelvington).